# How many ordered pairs $(A,B)$ there are if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\{ 1,2,3,4,5,\ldots,20 \}$ such that $A \cap B = \{2,5,6\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many ordered pairs $(A,B)$ there are if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\{ 1,2,3,4,5,\ldots,20 \}$ such that $A \cap B = \{2,5,6\}$?

Solution  :

Any number from $\{ 1,3,4,7,\ldots,20 \}$
can go either to $A$  or $B$ or neither

So we have $3^{17}$ possible subsets

I need  further explanation of the solution "which is not mine" .... thanks

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's not correct. $\binom{17}{3}$ is the number of ways to choose three more elements from $\{1,\dots,20\} \setminus \{2,5,6\}$. There are actually $2^{17}$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,20\}$ containing $\{2,5,6\}$, but we take $3^{17}$ and not $2^{17} \cdot 2^{17}$ to avoid having additional overlap between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Let $S:=\{1,3,4,7,\ldots, 20\}$. The number we are looking for is the same as the number of ordered pairs $(A',B')$ such that $A',B' \subset S$ and $A' \cap B' = \emptyset$. Counting such pairs is the same as counting all the possible ways we can assign elements of $S$ to either $A'$ or $B'$ (or neither). For any $s \in S$, there are 3 possibilities: (i) $s \in A'$ and $s \not\in B'$; (ii) $s \in B'$ and $s \not\in A'$; (iii) $s \not\in A'$, $s \not\in B'$. As $|S|=17$ and for each one we have 3 possibilities, the number of ways we can assign all elements of $S$ is then $3^{17}$.

Answer (score 3):

A handy way to formulate the problem is through the so-called 'membership' function. Given the set $S=\{1,...,20\}$ and subsets $A,B\subset S$ define $$f_{AB} : s\in S \mapsto (1_A(s),1_B(s)) \in \{0,1\}^2.$$
Here, e.g. $1_A(s)$ is 1 or 0 depending upon $s\in A$ or not.
Conversely, given any map  $f : S \to \{0,1\}^2$ there are unique
subsets $A,B\subset S$ for which $f$ is the membership function.
We thus have a bijection between couple of subsets $(A,B)$ and
membership functions. In the present context the goal is to calculate the number of membership functions satisfying the constraint  $f^{-1}((1,1))=  \{2,5,6\}$
(i.e. specifying the intersection $A\cap B=\{2,5,6\}$). The values of $f$ at $s\in S\setminus\{2,5,6\}$ is any of the three other possible values of memberships and as these choices are independent there are in total $3^{17}$ such membership functions, as already deduced through a combinatorial argument in a comment to the post.

For the present problem, the membership function carries no
particular advantage over the straight-forward combinatorial argument. But consider e.g.  the similar problem for the number of ordered triples $(A,B,C) \subset S$ with the constraint that $A\cap B\cap C=\{2,5,6\}$. Using combinatorics is perhaps less obvious here whereas the membership function, now taking values in $\{0,1\}^3$ (which is of cardinality $8=1+7$) immediately yields the answer $7^{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $A\cap B=\{2,4,6\}$

This mean $|A|,|B|\geq 3$
If $A=\{2,4,6\}$ then $B$ can be choose in $2^{17}$ ways then total number of ways of the type is $2^{17}$

If we choose $A=\{2,4,6,a\}$ where $a\in\{1,2,3,\dots,20\}-\{2,4,6\}$

Then we have $17 \choose 1$ choices of set $A$ and $2^{16}$ choices of set $B$
Total number of choices of this type are $2^{16}\binom{17}{1}$
Continuing in this way
We will get total number of choices are

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{17}\binom{17}{k}2^{17-k}=3^{17}$$